# Set custom map color in google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display multiple markers with different color like this

[see my demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/fzsg9pky/)

**In my code, I set custom color at outer side but problem at inner circle (fork and spoon)**

**I want circle behind fork and spoon as it is (white)**

[image]

**JS**

```
var myLatlng = {
  lat: 53.5617303,
  lng: 9.9835443
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: myLatlng,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  scrollwheel: false,

});

var $markerImage = document.querySelector('.markerImage'),
  markerImageSvg = $markerImage.innerHTML || '';

myLatlng.lng -= 0.006;

['#DF6047', '#ffd454', '#88D063'].forEach(function(color) {
  myLatlng.lng += 0.0099;

  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    clickable: false,
    icon: {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(markerImageSvg.replace('{{background}}', color))
    }
```

Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/fzsg9pky/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site.

Comment: this example is created by me@geocodezip...and i put it on fiddle ... not external...

Comment: jsfiddle is an external site (at least as far as stackoverflow is concerned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `<style> .st1:` from the SVG code.
2. Add the `fill={{background}}` to each of the paths in the SVG code.
3. Make the javascript `replace()` command replace all of the instances: `markerImageSvg.replace(/{{background}}/g, color)`

See updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fzsg9pky/5/

Comment: Thank you... it's working.. but only in chrome not in Firefox... can you please help me to find what is wrong??

Comment: @Nidhi Not sure if you still have this issue, but in current version of Firefox (64.0) it works properly